# PHP can't seem to store in SESSION or COOKIE on mobile

Tags: php, android, session, cookies

I have an application that takes some user-submitted form data and stores that info in $_COOKIE and $_SESSION if the cookies don't get set. It works perfectly on laptop, but on mobile, it isn't working. I have tried echoing out/ var_dumping SESSION and COOKIE and on my phone it is showing BOTH as completely empty! what is happening?

Comment: its not php its the browser

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Enable the Cookies in your mobile browser.

The following link will give you the solution. https://www.vishwamatri.com/enableCookies.php